# ALB in front of lambda returns 502 randomly after not running lambda for awhile

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

So I get intermittent failures from my ALB if I don't run my lambda for awhile. Sometimes a couple of subsequent calls will fix it. But sometimes it keeps returning 502s until I log into console and invoke the lambda directly. And then requests through the ALB will start working again.

I don't have access to logs at the moment because I'm waiting on some enterprise security approvals in my company. Which could take a couple of weeks......

I do have ~200 ips available in the subnet and I'm the only one invoking it so that should be ruled out.

I came across this [aws doc](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-invoke-error-502-500) about a ResourceNotReadyException. But it just says to wait for the resource to be ready.... And it seems like sometimes the ALB isn't actually activating the lambda to become available.

Anyone have any insight?